# Xpath and wildcards

Tags: c#, xpath, screen-scraping, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have tried several combinations without success.  The full xpath to that data is `.//*[@id='detail_row_seek_37878']/td`  The problem is the number portion '37878' changes for each node and thus I can't use a foreach to loop through the nodes.  Is there some way to use a wildcard and reduce the xpath to `.//*[@id='detail wildcard`, in an effort to bypass the absolute value portion? I am using html agility pack on this.

```
 HtmlNode ddate = node.SelectSingleNode(".//*[@id='detail_row_seek_37878']/td");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Extract the portion that doesn't change:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'detail_row_seek')]/td
```

**Related Techniques and Functions**

To match elements whose `id` attribute contains the string `_row_` **at the 7th character**:

```
//*[substring(@id, 7, 5)='_row_']/td
```

To match elements whose `id` attribute **contains** the text `detail_` at any position:

```
//*[contains(@id, 'detail_')]/td
```

To match elements whose `id` attribute **ends with** the text `detail_row_seek`:

```
//*['detail_row_seek' = substring(@id, 
        string-length(@id) - string-length('detail_row_seek') + 1)]/td
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could you explain to me what the 1 and 15 represent. I would like to shorten it up to just detail and a 1,6 doesn't work.

Comment: @JRB - They identified the location of the desired substring. However, I am silly and forgot about `starts-with` for a minute. See my update.